# How to move content to the next page if the content is longer than the page in jspdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

How to move content to the next page if the content is longer than the page and make the page doesn't overlap in jsPDF and React.js? Now I use the **pdf.html()** function to generate html/react elements to pdf and still stuck to find a way to automatically move to next page if content is exceed the height of page.

My code for report template:
https://pastebin.com/tWP4LMk2

And this is for rendering the template to string to generate as a pdf

```
const ComponentString = renderToString(
    <ReportTemplate
      title='Example Pdf file'
      type={printType}
      data={data}
    />
  );

  useEffect(() => {
      generatePdf({
        ComponentString,
        fileName: 'docs.pdf'
      });
    }
  }, [printType]);
```

my generatePdf code:

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

export const generatePdf = ({ ComponentString, fileName }) => {
  const pdf = new jsPDF({
    format: "a4",
    unit: "px"
  });

  pdf.html(ComponentString, {
    callback(doc) {
      doc.save(fileName);
    } 
  });
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Depending on screen size this may always occur perhaps even on the next page.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I see, so what the optimal / best solution for this problem?